# How does the range for inner contents of braces work in Vim?

Tags: vim

From Drew Neil's fantastic book "Practical Vim" I learned what you can do with the `:g` command. However, there is one expression I don't get.

`:g/{/ .+1,/}/-1 sort`

This sorts all lines between braces in the file alphabetically. The general form of this command is

`:global/{pattern}/[cmd]`

, with `[cmd]` consisting of `[range] [cmd]`. I get that the search pattern is the starting point, so `:g/{/`is clear. Then follows the range `.+1,/}/-1`, with `.` being the current line (i.e. every line matching the pattern `{` ), `+1` adding a one-line offset, `,` separating the start of the range from the end, `/}/` saying "until the closing brace" and `-1` subtracting one line to match only the inner contents of the braces. 
What I don't get is the `/}/` part. What are the slashes needed for? Why is it not possible to just write `}`?

**EDIT:**
From Vimhelp 10.3 I now know that `/}/`is the search pattern used for the upper range boundary. Which leaves me still confused about the second `/` here. So the updated question is: **Why do I need the second `/` before `-1`?**

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that after you've successfully made it though the complex parsing of the command (what belongs to `:global` vs. what comprises the range of the `:sort`), you're confused by the rather simple range syntax.

Comment: I always thought of the search pattern in ex commands as being fixed to the second position in the command here. E.g. in `:s/search/replace`. That is (now) obviously not true and it blows up my mind what I can do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ranges, the `/.../` are always needed to tell Vim: *this is a pattern, search for the next match and position the cursor there; that's where I want to start/end the range*. If you look at [`:help :range`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange), a literal `}` is not allowed there; Vim wants a line number, or a symbol representing such, a mark, or a search pattern. The only allowed variation is `?...?` for an upwards search.

When you try out your suggested variant, you'll get

```
E492: Not an editor command: .+1,}-1 sort
```

Another way to motivate this is by abstracting from the concrete `{` ... `}` delimiters. Imagine how the range would look if you wanted a range inside `foo` ... `bar`. What if the range were `000` ... `999`; Vim would not be able to differentiate between a literal number range (line 999) and the search (next line that contains `999`).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But I'm still confused about the `/`after the `}`. Is it just to tell vim "search pattern is from here to here?"

Comment: The second `/` is optional if nothing else would follow it. But here, you have the `-1` offset, and also the `sort` command (no, the whitespace doesn't end the pattern, as there can be whitespace inside a pattern as well). So this would work (to print the range): `:.+1,/}`